# Entity Framework doesn't open the certificate correctly

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, aes

I have a procedure to open a certificate, basically:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_OPENCCKEY] WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER AS  
   OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY CCKEY
        DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE CERTCC;
```

And NO, I don't want to let my user open it directly.

So, I'm trying to return a view wich uses that certificate to decrypt some of credit card data and i'm just doing like this:

```
public List<VW_CREDITCARDS> ListCreditCardByPersonID(int PersonId)
        {
            EntityMgr ent = new EntityMgr ();
            ent.ExecuteFunction("SP_OPENCCKEY");
            return ent.VW_CREDITCARDS.Where(p => p.PES_IDPERSON== PersonId).ToList();
        }
```

For some reason the results are returning NULL (probably because EF hasn't opened the key).

Some hints?

Comment: I know nothing about certifcates but since this is a stored procedure EF should be invoking it the same way anyone else would invoke this stored procedure. So, if you - using **the same** credentials (i.e. connection string) are able to invoke this stored procedure successfully EF should be able to as well. I also don't understand what "results are returning NULL" means. Is it ListCreditCardByPersonID returning null (this does not seem possible), is the procedure returning nulls (where - the snippet you posted does not show corresponding code)

Comment: When you try to read a column that was previoulsy encrypted with a certificate and forget to open it, it will return null because SQLServer doesnt know what to do with DecryptByKey.

Comment: Could you try this? : Make a new sproc that first executes `SP_OPENCCKEY` then does `SELECT TOP(1) FROM VW_CEDITCARDS` (or whatever it's called). Then execute this sproc and materialize results. Does it work?

Comment: Try running the stored procedure from the management studio with the same parameters as EF and see what you will get. If you have the correct result try connecting to the database with exactly the same credentials you use for EF and do the same. Try using pure ADO.NET (SqlConnection, SqlCommand and friends) with the same (provider) connection string as you use for EF to invoke the stored procedure. The above should tell you where the problem is. I feel this is related to permissions - you don't have rights to access/use certificates/decryption whith credentials you use in your EF app.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like EF just doesn't work that way. Need to return the results with the opened certificate on one single command.

Comment: I am not sure if this is helpful: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlsecurity/archive/2007/11/29/open-symmetric-key-scope-in-sql-server.aspx

Answer (score 1):

To decrypt before querying sensitive data, all you need to do is to use a DbTransaction in the EF ObjectContext connection.

I.e.

1. connection.Open();
2. connection.BeginTransaction();
3. execute your "OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY..." command or stored procedure with ExecuteStoreCommand
4. execute your sensitive data queries, stored procedures etc.
5. Commit or Rollback you transaction if required

This forces EF to maintain the same db connection because you have started a db transaction and it makes sense because you might execute a whole bunch of SP's as part of the same db transaction.

Try that. It works for me.

Thyago